# I want to create div's in javascript so I do not have to sit there and make a hundred different divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Okay so instead of typing out a hundred div tags in the hmtl I would like to generate them in javascript and have them show on the page. Here is what I have, but it will not work.

```
var arry = {};
for(var i = 0; i<100; i++){
  arry[i] = i;
}
  for each (var x in arry){
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = x;
    document.getElementById('body').appendChild(div);
  }
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('body')` - do you have an element with `id="body"`?

Answer (score 0):

This will create one hundred `divs`, each with a text node inside containing the number of the `div`.

```js
var body = document.querySelector('body');
for(var x = 0; x < 100; x++) {  
  var div = document.createElement("div"); 
  var text = document.createTextNode(x);
  div.appendChild(text);
  body.appendChild(div);
}
```

Comment: When submitting to StackOverflow, please try to explain your code, and not just post it. We are trying to teach people

Comment: This works but it just makes divs with them as numbers. So on the page it shows 0 1 2 3 4 5 etc..

Comment: What would you like in the divs?

Answer (score 0):

body is not an id, it is a tag.  you need

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div);
```

Comment: That is all I needed to do and now it works awesome thank you!!

Comment: Please mark as answer then.  Just made my account and I'm trying to build my rep here ;)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can do this:

```js
var divs = '';

for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    divs += '<div id="id_' + i + '">Div ' + i + '</div>';
}

document.write(divs);
```

Comment: This works but it puts div 01 div 02 etc.. I got it to work though just needed to change the document.getElementById('body').appendChild(div); to document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div);

Comment: It is just an example. You can modify the code to put anything you like instead of `Div + i`